# Does inoERP software work with RFID barcodes?

Tags: rfid, inventory

We are looking to start using software to replacement spreadsheets but need to be able to use RFID technology. We really like the inoERP system but can't seem to get an answer to the question if it works with RFID. We'll be using Zebra RFID scanners and printers.

Comment: Not sure if there was input from my response.....but, is it fair to say that if we are using API's, we can use the RFID scanner to send API commands to the MySQL database to create the RF ID tags...then they are are just column entries?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific on your question :

- You want to use RFID for what?
- Creating inventory transactions?
- Creating manufacturing transactions?
- For Shipping purposes?
- For receiving purposes?
- On a POS screen
- etc

Generally, you can use RFID for many transactions but if something is not available, then use the APIs (http://api.inoerp.com/).

The application provides 1000+ APIs and allows you to use Javascript on the server side (though it's a Go server, not npm).

Comment: Thank you for the response! To add clarity, we want to use RFID to initially track boxes of product when it arrives in receiving until it leaves in shipping. We plan to use handheld RFID readers to enter the data when it's received and computers/handhelds to modify fields as it moves through the plant. We had been thinking the handhelds would have their own software communicating through the API to the database. To answer your question more directly, we would like to use RFID labels to do inventory, manufacturing, shipping & receiving. No need to the POS side.

Comment: There are two options. 
Fixed RFID readers: attached to a specific location. So when you put an item in a nearby location, the application would know the position and send it to the application. In this approach, you usually connect the RFID reader to a server or a local machine that sends the information to ERP. This is mostly used for tracking internal material movement, i.e., moving from a storage location to production or between two storage locations.

Comment: Handheld readers: These readers need human action. i.e., you scan specific RFID on a product. Mostly you develop your own app or, if android, then use any android app to read the information.
Next, you send the information from the app to your server.